# How can I create a instance of TextStyle based MaterialTheme.typography.body2 and Color.Red when I use Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I know I can use Code A to create a instance of `TextStyle` with `color`, `fontFamily` and etc.

Now I hope to get a instance of `TextStyle` based `MaterialTheme.typography.body2`, and I hope that the style has customized color `Red`.

How can I do?  BTW, Code B is wrong.

**Code A**

```
var style = TextStyle(
        color = Color.Red
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 14.sp
    )
```

**Code B**

```
var style: TextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
style.color=  Color.Red
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `TextStyle.copy`

Like this

```
var style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.copy(color = Color.Red)
```